# Forcing Hash Join Query Plans using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, query, performance

I'm currently testing PostGIS 2.0 in a Greenplum Appliance (Postgres 8.2 based) and have hit an incompatibility between PostGIS and the MPP Greenplum environment.

The basic query below can't be processed in parallel because it's query plan uses a nested loop for the ST_Contains operator. Using a hash join would solve the problem.

```
SELECT pnts.gid, bdys.pid
  FROM bdys
  INNER JOIN pnts
  ON ST_Contains(bdys.geom, pnts.geom);
```

I've tried using the following SET commands unsuccessfully

```
SET enable_nestloop = OFF;
SET enable_hashjoin = ON;
```

Is there any way to force the query or a variant of a point in polygon query to use a hash join?

Comment: Did you ever solve this. Have you tried rewritting the query to: SELECT pnts.gid, bdys.pid FROM bdys, pnts
 WHERE ST_Contains(bdys.geom, pnts.geom); along with the set commands.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I gave it a try but no change unfortunately!